# List out of bounds due to loop

Tags: python, loops, bounds

im trying to make a function that looks through a list and deletes all odd numbers. I have a problem where my loop is going out of bounds and im not sure how to fix it, can anyone help? Thanks

```
def isEven(number):
    if(number % 2) == 0 and (number != 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def only_even(intList):
    for i in range(0, len(intList)):
        if(isEven(intList[i])) == False:
           del intList[i]
    return intList

print(only_even([5, 8, 17, 6, 0, 20, 3]))
```

Comment: How come zero is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `del`, you are changing the length of the list, but the `for` loop is trying to iterate over the original length of the list, so eventually, it will go out of bounds of the list.  That is, `len(intList)` is not evaluated every time `for` loops.

A solution to this would be to create a new list from the old list and return that, like so:

```
def only_even(intList):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(intList)):
        if isEven(intList[i]) == True:
            new_list.append(intList[i])
    return new_list
```

Now your print statement will work:

```
>>> print(only_even([5, 8, 17, 6, 0, 20, 3]))
[8, 6, 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the list is going out of bounds is because you are iterating over a range of the original size while shrinking the list!

```
def only_even(intList):
    intList[:] = [i for i in intList if isEven(i)]
    return intList
```

I'm doing a slice assignment `[:]` to preserve the exact semantics of mutating and returning the list. If you just want to return the list it's even shorter

```
def only_even(intList):
    return [i for i in intList if isEven(i)]
```

You can also simplify your is even function, since it already evaluates to True/False

```
def isEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0 and number != 0   # Why isn't 0 even?
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain each step, and simplifying the iseven function : )

Answer (score 1):

```
def only_even(intList):
    intList[:] = filter(isEven, intList)
    return intList
```

Or, if you don't need to modify the list in place:

```
def only_even(intList):
    return list(filter(isEven, intList))
```

Comment: Regardless of which is faster (I haven't tested), what makes you think this is even relevant? ;)

Comment: @gnibbler: Just tested them on Python 2.7.3, and they are within 10% of each other.

Comment: Oh, I meant how long it takes to type them into an answer :p